# Как сформировать MySQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется таблица: Work
В этой таблице есть поля: id(идентификатор работы), catid(идентификатор типа работы), name(полное ФИО сотрудника), start_date(дата начала работы), end_date(дата окончания работы).
Обращаюсь через PHP.
Первое, что мне надо было сделать это получить сумму затраченного времени сотрудником на работы с типом 1 и отдельно с типом 2 за год в этой таблице. Я реализовал это следующим образом:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) - 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date))/3600) FROM service_calendar WHERE title='Петров Петр 
Петрович' AND catid='1' AND start_date LIKE '".$year."-%-%'") or die('Запрос не удался: 
' .mysql_error());
```

Я остановился на моменте, при котором мне надо обработать следующий случай: Надо получить сумму этих двух работ, но если у сотрудника две записи работы в один день, одна работа с catid = 1, а другая с catid = 2, то мне нужно из продолжительности работы в часах с catid 2 вычесть продолжительность работы с catid 1. То есть мне надо получить разницу времени затраченное на эти работы и получить их сумму.
Можно ли такое вообще получить средствами SQL запроса?

Comment: версию СУБД в студию. зы: `start_date >= '{$year}-01-01'` вам там группировку по cat_id надо делать, а не фильтрикацию и два запроса. Потом распихать значения  в два столбца, и уже к ним можно приделать разницу

Comment: Версия mySql 5.7.33, спасибо за совет

Comment: Как определяется ``продолжительность работы в часах с catid 2``?

Comment: Аналогичным образом как и для catid 1